# In `atop`, does MEM (the percentage figure) reflect PSIZE or only RSIZE?

Tags: memory, atop

When PSIZE is available, does `atop` use it to make the MEM figure more useful, or does the MEM figure in `atop` always reflect RSIZE (RSS)?

The manpage seems unhelpful.

> MEM
>
> The occupation percentage of this process related to the available capacity for this resource on system level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested on `atop-2.3.0-8.fc27.x86_64`.

RSIZE, not PSIZE, is used when sorting by memory usage (use the <kbd>M</kbd> key), and for the MEM column.

```
RSIZE   PSIZE   MEM
311.0M  260.2M  4%
303.3M  288.1M  4%
217.6M  123.1M  3%
```

More detailed output:

```
  PID    TID  MINFLT  MAJFLT  VSTEXT  VSLIBS   VDATA  VSTACK   VSIZE   RSIZE   PSIZE   VGROW   RGROW  SWAPSZ  RUID      EUID       MEM  CMD

 1782      -    2413       0     16K  96480K  361.5M    288K    3.8G  311.0M  260.2M  10772K   9448K      0K  alan  alan        4%  gnome-shell
 1455      -       0       0    280K  30860K  340.8M    132K    1.0G  303.3M  288.1M      0K      0K      0K  root  root        4%  packagekitd
13561      -   41988      34    196K  143.2M  298.0M    136K    2.2G  217.6M  123.1M  255.3M  139.0M      0K  alan  alan        3%  Web Content
13333      -   25219       0    196K  119.6M  277.9M    144K    2.1G  190.9M  111.9M      0K   3560K      0K  alan  alan        2%  Web Content
```

https://www.atoptool.nl/screenshots.php

> The memory percentage (column MEM) shows the **resident memory occupation by this process**, because that is what matters when your system starts swapping.

https://www.atoptool.nl/download/case_leakage.pdf

> The memory details (subcommand 'm') show the current RSS per process in the column RSIZE and (as a percentage of the total memory installed) in the column MEM.